# transform JSON to hashmap in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, mongoid

I am trying to convert a json file which contain object and array to a JSON file.

Below is the JSON file

```
{
    "localbusiness":{
        "name": "toto",
        "phone": "+11234567890"
    },
    "date":"05/02/2016",
    "time":"5:00pm",    
    "count":"4",
    "userInfo":{
        "name": "John Doe",
        "phone": "+10987654321",
        "email":"john.doe@unknown.com",
        "userId":"user1234333"
    }
}
```

my goal is to save this is a database such as MongoId. I would like to use map to get something like:

```
localbusiness_name => "toto",
localbusiness_phone => "+11234567890",
date => "05/02/2016",
...
userInfo_name => "John Doe"
...
```

I have tried map but it's not splitting the array of local business or userInfo

```
def format_entry
  ps = @params.map do | h |
    ps.merge!(h)
    @@logger.info("entry #{h}")
  end
  @@logger.info("formatting the data #{ps}")
  ps
end
```

I do not really how to parse each entry and rebuild the name

Comment: Is `@params` the JSON hash or the Rails variable? Is it possible to show the output of `format_entry`?

Comment: @ElijahSchutz format entry is not working is merge fail. params is the JSON hash

Comment: Do you have the JSON file as text, and you want to convert it to a nested hash? If so, `require 'json'; myhash = JSON.parse(text);` will do that.

Comment: It seems to me, @JimStewart, the OP needs more than just this. The hash must be 'flattened' too.

Comment: You're right, I misread.

Comment: In the example code, `ps` doesn't exist as a hash until _after_ `map` returns; when `ps.merge!` is evaluated, `ps` is still `nil`.

Comment: Come to that, if `@params` is a hash, then `h` will be an array with 2 elements, one the key and one the value. Also, `Hash#map` is just `Enumerable#map`, whose return value is an array, not a hash.

Comment: @Seb did my solution work for you? If so, can you mark it as the accepted answer. If not, what is still unclear to you?

Comment: @Dbz Yes it works. thqnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like to me you are trying to "flatten" the inner hashes into one big hash. Flatten being incorrect because you want to prepend the hash's key to the sub-hash's key. This will require looping through the hash, and then looping again through each sub hash. This code example will only work if you have 1 layer deep. if you have multiple layers, then I would suggest making two methods, or a recursive method.

```
@business = { # This is a hash, not a json blob, but you can take json and call JSON.parse(blob) to turn it into a hash.
    "localbusiness":{
        "name": "toto",
        "phone": "+11234567890"
    },
    "date":"05/02/2016",
    "time":"5:00pm",
    "count":"4",
    "userInfo":{
        "name": "John Doe",
        "phone": "+10987654321",
        "email":"john.doe@unknown.com",
        "userId":"user1234333"
    }
}

@squashed_business = Hash.new

@business.each do |k, v|
  if v.is_a? Hash
    v.each do |key, value|
      @squashed_business.merge! (k.to_s + "_" + key.to_s) => value
    end
  else
    @squashed_business.merge! k => v
  end
end
```

I noticed that you are getting "unexpected" outcomes when enumerating over a hash `@params.each { |h| ... }`  because it gives you both a key and a value. Instead you want to do `@params.each { |key, value| ... }` as I did in the above code example.

Comment: No. My answer wouldn't improve yours. As soon as I see it I upvoted it and was about to delete mine when I saw your comment.

Comment: Thank you. We're all just trying to help! I think you did something cool/similar on your answer using `class`?

Comment: I found your way more efficient, more direct. And the important part is the OP has a solution. You pointed it right. We are all here to help.